# Simplify counting with two for loops (using stream)

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8, java-stream

I have this code and I want to write it using streams.
I need to check if hList contains all dFoods elements.

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i< dFoods.size(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j< hList.size(); j++){
        if(hList.get(j).title.equals(dFoods.get(i).name) && hList.get(j).time.equals(dFoods.get(i).timestamp)){
            count ++;
        }
    }
}
if(count != dFoods.Elements.size()){
    System.out.println("Not all dFoods elements are in a hList");
}
```

I've tried

```
dFoods.forEach(df -> {
        hList.stream().filter(hl -> df.Name.equals(hl.title) && df.Timestamp.equals(hl.time)).forEach(hl -> {
            System.out.println(df.Name + " " + df.Timestamp);
        });
    });
```

And it is writing out correctly but I need to count and that can't be done this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dFoods.stream()
  .allMatch(df -> 
      hList.stream
        .anyMatch(hl -> df.Name.equals(hl.title) && df.Timestamp.equals(hl.time)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dFoods.forEach(df -> {
        hList.stream().filter(hl -> df.Name.equals(hl.title) && df.Timestamp.equals(hl.time)).count();
    });
```

Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

Firstly find a similarity count between `dFoods` and `hList`.

```
Long countOfMatching = dFoods.stream()
        .filter(df ->
                hList.stream()
                        .anyMatch(hl -> df.Name.equals(hl.title) && df.Timestamp.equals(hl.time)))
        .count();
```

Inner stream is return `true` if dFood's element is in the `hList`. And filtering if return `true` to outer stream for collecting. Now you can get the similarity count of between two list. Now apply if match list size of two list with this found value. If you wants only the if all contains as boolean result, do it like this;

```
Boolean allMatched = dFoods.stream()
        .allMatch(df ->
                hList.stream()
                        .anyMatch(hl -> df.Name.equals(hl.title) && df.Timestamp.equals(hl.time)));
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution of greg delivering a boolean state would seem best if sufficient.

```
int count = (int) dFoods.stream()
    .mapToLong(
        f -> hList.stream()
            .filter(h -> h.title.equals(f.name) && h.time.equals(f.timestamp))
            .count())
    .sum();
```

Where `hList` must be implicitly final.